# Pushing to bitbucket without entering password

Tags: java, git, cmd, push, bitbucket

I'm doing a project in java to implement GIT in an IDE. I wanted to know how to do a push without getting the password prompt. I'm using bitbucket. After doing a lot of research I found a command.

```
 git push --repo https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/example9.git
```

This code for push works fine in linux. But when i use the same command in windows cmd it shows the following error.

```
    No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

I have also tried using ssh instead of http. but it gives me a prompt asking

```
are you sure? (yes/no)
```

I don't want to get any prompts after executing the push command.
I tried configuring the .git/config file and giving the origin as master. Nothing seems to be working. Can anyone plz help. I'm stuck here from a long time.. Thank you!

Comment: do you use the windows file path syntax when you try to push?

Comment: Since you are getting the message "No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.", it appears that connectivity is not the issue. Why don't you follow the suggestion, and specify a branch?